# Determine all $(p,q)$ where Lorentz quasi-norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p,q}}$ is norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, cumulative-distribution-functions

On a measure space $(X,\mu)$, for $0<p,q<\infty$ the Lorentz space $L^{p,q}(\mu)$ is defined by $$\|f\|_{L^{p,q}(\mu)}:=p^\frac1q\|t\cdot\mu(|f|>t)^\frac1p\|_{L^q(\mathbb R_+,\frac{dt}t)}=p^\frac1q\left(\int_0^\infty t^{q-1}\mu(|f|>t)^\frac qpdt\right)^{1/q},$$
with usual modification for $q=\infty$:
$$\|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}(\mu)}:=\|t\cdot\mu(|f|>t)^\frac1p\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R_+,\frac{dt}t)}=\sup_{t>0}t\cdot\mu(|f|>t)^\frac 1p.$$

Although for $1<p,q<\infty$, the space $L^{p,q}(\mu)$ is normable, but the quantatity $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p,q}(\mu)}$ itself may only be a quasi-norm.

I want to determine all $(p,q)$ such that $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p,q}(\mu)}$ is a norm, i.e. $\|f+g\|_{L^{p,q}(\mu)}\le \|f\|_{L^{p,q}(\mu)}+\|g\|_{L^{p,q}(\mu)}$ for all $f,g$.

In Grafakos' *Classical Fourier analysis*, he mentioned the example $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=1-x$ on the space $x\in[0,1]$. This only gives a partial result where $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p,q}}$ is not a norm. For more general case I haven't found a reference about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lorentz himself proved that $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p,q}}$ is a norm if and only if $1\leq q\leq p<\infty$ (G.G. Lorentz, *On the theory of spaces $\Lambda$*, Pacific J. Math. 1 (1951), 411–429). I don't know much about those spaces myself, but I found this result, along with other nice ones, neatly summarized in the introduction of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.0647) (S. Barza, V. Kolyada, J. Soria, *Sharp constants related to the triangle inequality in Lorentz spaces* (2007)). Basically it seems the decreasing rearrangement form of this (quasi-)norm tends to be preferred, as it's much simpler to handle and doesn't even end up depending on $\mu$.